# Dynamic DataSource for Droplist in Content Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, validation

I have a Droplist for Approvers and the DataSource of Droplist to `/SharedData/Approvers`.

I don't want the current user to have his own name in the list.
For example, DataSource List is having A, B and C

When A logs in, it should show B and C but not A. Or it should be validated when A selects himself as Approver.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible via both a custom field implementation or field validation. Below is the code for both ways.

**Solution 1 - A Custom Validation**

You should implement a class which will extend the `StandardValidator`. The code snippet is provided below to create a custom validation for the droplist.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserValidation : StandardValidator
{
    protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
    {
        var selectedValue = ControlValidationValue;

        var username = Context.User.LocalName;

        if (!selectedValue.IsNullOrEmpty() && selectedValue.Equals(username))
        {
            Text = GetText($"Field {GetFieldDisplayName()} cannot select your own name");
            return ValidatorResult.FatalError;
        }

        return ValidatorResult.Valid;
    }

    protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
    {
        return GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
    }

    public override string Name => "User Validator";
}
```

In the code above, I have use the `LocalName` property. This property will return me only the name. Example, Admin.

Note that this piece of code will validate the username against the item name. It is feasible check the username against a field on the items from the list but it will require additional code to retrieve the selected item then read the field.

Once you have deployed the above code, you will need to create a new validation item under the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules`.

[image]

Change the `Type` to match your namespace. Also, you need to assign the newly created validation rule to the field.

**Solution 2 - A Custom Field**

You can implement a custom droplist which extend the `ValueLookupEx` from the namespace `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor` in the `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`. The purpose will be to remove the current user from the list of items if it matches.

```
public class CustomDroplist : ValueLookupEx
{
    protected override Item[] GetItems(Item current)
    {
        var items = base.GetItems(current);

        var username = Sitecore.Context.User.LocalName;

        var resultItems = items.Where(w => !w.Name.Equals(username)).ToArray();

        return resultItems;
    }
}
```

Once implemented, deploy the code and load the content editor. Then, switch the database to `core` and navigate to the path `/sitecore/system/Field types/List Types` and create a new field using the template `Template field type`.

[image]

Update the assembly and class with yours.

**Outcome**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can specify custom logic to resolve the source of the field using a `code:` declaration and setting it to your custom Class.

Include a reference to `Sitecore.Buckets.dll` and create a class which implements `IDataSource`:

```
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace Sitecore.Sharedsource.Data.FieldSources
{
    public class CustomFieldDataSource : Sitecore.Buckets.FieldTypes.IDataSource
    {
        public Item[] ListQuery(Item item)
        {
            var items = item.Axes.SelectItems("./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Homepage']/path/to/userlist/*");
            var username = Sitecore.Context.User.LocalName;
            var resultItems = items.Where(w => !w.Name.Equals(username)).ToArray();

            return resultItems;
        }
    }
}
```

You can now set the field source to `code:Sitecore.Sharedsource.Data.FieldSources.CustomFieldDataSource, Sitecore.Sharedsource`. The code runs from the context of the context item, i.e. the currently selected item in the content tree.

You can use this syntax for any field that runs the query through the `getLookupSourceItems` pipeline, such a Droplink, Droplist, Multilist, Treelist, Checklist etc.

Alternatively you could create a custom prefix and handle this yourself using a custom pipeline processor instead in `getLookupSourceItems` pipeline.

You can read more in these [blog posts by John West](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-7-custom-classes-as-data-template-field-sources) and [Raul Jimenez](https://blog.rauljimenez.co.uk/getting-to-the-source/).